# "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" on unit tests

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing, php-ziparchive, undefined-symbol

I'm getting the following error only when I try to build the unit tests of an iPhone static library:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive dealloc] in libMyProject.a(ZipArchive.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libMyProject.a(ZipArchive.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Building the original project works fine.

What can I be missing?

It should be noted that ZipArchive is a .mm file that references the *libz.dylib* framework, which is referenced both in the original project and in the test project.

Additionally, the usual Build Settings suspects have the following values:

**Framework Search Paths**: "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks" "$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks"

**Other Linker Flags**: -all_load -lxml2 - ObjC

**Header Search Paths**: /usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in this [post](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/issues/detail?id=4).

For some reason that eludes me, the compiler needed the `ZipArchive.mm` file to be renamed to .m when the static library is used in another project (the test project, in this case).

Comment: follow this [issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/61). 
In project's Build Settings, add `-lc++` to Other Linker Flags can solve this problem if you don't want to rename .mm file into .m file.

Answer (score 4):

This typically occurs for one of two reasons:

1. You copied a framework or system header directly to your project folder instead of *adding* it with a reference through XCode
2. You've installed multiple SDKs, and the wrong framework or header is being referenced.  Most frameworks aren't "Developer" frameworks.  SenTestingKit.framework is an example of a developer framework, UIKit.framework isn't.  Oddly, there are two different places that Developer Frameworks exist. In the /Developers/~ folder in XCode, and also in the SDK Developers folder.  The default behavior is to reference the framework in XCode's developer folder.  To override this, enter "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks" in "Framework Search Paths".  Or in the case of an imported header or library, go the corresponding field and add "$(SDKROOT)/..."

Make sure your search paths are <strike>the same</strike> correct for all Targets:[image: Search Path]

If you are using multiple SDKs, the wrong version of the Developer Frameworks could get added (like SenTestingKit).  Manually enter the the correct one under Framework Search Paths with

> $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks

[image]

Comment: "Framework search paths" is empty on the original project and has value "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks" on the test project. If I remove that I get file not found on <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>.

Comment: That's the configuration I already have on the test project (see question). If what you mean is adding it to the original project, then I just tested it and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @hgpc your header search path should either be blank, or should reference the SDK folder: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

Comment: Header Search Paths is blank on both projects. However, test projects need Framework Search Pats to point to "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks". In any case, the problem was something related to C++ code in static libraries. See my answer. And thanks a lot for trying to help.